# issue using incrementing ingest in jdbc connector

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use an incrementing ingest to produce a message to a topic on update of a table in mysql. It works using timestamp but doesn't seem to be working using incrementing column mode. When I insert a new row into the table, I do not see any message published to the topic.

```
{
            "_comment": " --- JDBC-specific configuration below here  --- ",
            "_comment": "JDBC connection URL. This will vary by RDBMS. Consult your manufacturer's handbook for more information",
            "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lte?user=root&password=tiger",

            "_comment": "Which table(s) to include",
            "table.whitelist": "candidate_score",

            "_comment": "Pull all rows based on an timestamp column. You can also do bulk or incrementing column-based extracts. For more information, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_config_options.html#mode",
            "mode": "incrementing",

            "_comment": "Which column has the timestamp value to use?  ",
            "incrementing.column.name": "attempt_id",

            "_comment": "If the column is not defined as NOT NULL, tell the connector to ignore this  ",
            "validate.non.null": "true",

            "_comment": "The Kafka topic will be made up of this prefix, plus the table name  ",
            "topic.prefix": "mysql-"
    }
```

`attempt_id` is an auto incrementing non null column which is also the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its my fault. I was listening to the wrong topic.